# update geographic coordinates into db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This problem has already been addressed in other posts and other forums around the network but i don't understand where wrong.
I've this code javascript for find user's position:

```
if(!!navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocalizzami);
}
else {
  alert("Geolocalizzazione non supportata");
}

function geolocalizzami(position) {
  document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;  
}
```

and i can print with

```
<label id='lon' /></label>
```

and ok. I need of loading these data into database. I know I need to use jquery and ajax. The ajax code into an html page its serv me for find the coordinates and send these data, with the post method, to php page. here i can using  **$_POST['value']** for work with the data.
An example, found in internet, that i use is:

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'page2.php',
        data: {
            'lat': position.coords.latitude,
            'lng': position.coords.longitude
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function (result) {
            // If your backend page sends something back
            alert(result);
        }
    });

  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
echo $lat = $_POST['lat'];
echo $lng = $_POST['lng'];
?>
```

Why **$lat** and **$lng** are empty? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo $lat = $_POST['lat'];
echo $lng = $_POST['lng'];
```

to

```
echo $lat = $_GET['lat'];
echo $lng = $_GET['lng'];
```

Or

```
type: 'get',
```

to

```
type: 'post',
```

You are mixing `POST` and `GET` which are 2 different things in PHP. I would recommend to use tool like postman to see what is happening. This sometimes gives you more information about what is going on.

For testing purpese you could change the `$_POST` to `$_GET` and try:

```
$.get( "page2.php?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lng="+position.coords.longitude, function( data ) {
 console.log(data)
});
```

Also it's more common to use

```
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng']; // POST

echo $lat;
echo $lng;
```

Or just

```
echo $_GET['lat'];
echo $_GET['lng']; // or POST
```

Comment: The mixing was my inattention, but thanks for pointing to me. Anyway I corrected using the post method on both sides but I keep seeing nothing.

Comment: They are still the first weapons with javascript, but I put your code in place of $ .ajax ({...}) (right?). With both get and post, but I keep seeing nothing.

Comment: Are you sure `page2.php` is at the location you expect it to be? Have you checked that `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` actually contain a value?

Comment: As I said before, I'm recently on javascript, in fact, a first mistake I made was to put the ajax function in page.html and send the data to page2.php. Now I put everything together but it only works when the case of success prints with 'document write (date)'. in fact, having not put a button (I need that I'm doing it all tot), loop the page on itself, displaying the rescheduled I want. if I type with 'alert' or 'consol.log' it shows me the code in full.